# POST request does not respond

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to save some photos to a folder on my machine. In the previous question, I asked about how to fix it in a test program. It works there just fine, but I moved the code to the main program and it just refuses to work there.

When I submit the frontend in the Controller the function "ProcessReport" is activated and when it is finished the code just moves on because of the return statement. => The function which supposed to get the photos and process them into the folder just isn't activated.

How do I combine those two functions so that it'll work?

Here's the code:

## Model:

```
public class ReportModel
{
    //The properties which suppose to get the images
    public List<string> Name { get; set; } 
    public List<IFormFile> File { get; set; }

    //The rest of the code.
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public string category { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Problem description")]
    public string remarks { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string userID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Report Status")]
    public statusOfReport statReport { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Priority")]
    public string statUrgence { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Latitude")]
    public string coordLat { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Longitude")]
    public string coordLong { get; set; }
}
```

## Controller:

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult ProcessReport(ReportModel report)
    {
        if (ReportDAO.addReport(report))
            return View("Index");
        return View("Create");
    }

    [Obsolete]
    private IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv;

    [Obsolete]
    public ReportController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.hostingEnv = env;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Upload()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Obsolete]
    public IActionResult Upload(ReportModel upload)
    {

        var FileDic = "Files";

        string FilePath = Path.Combine(hostingEnv.WebRootPath, FileDic);

        if (!Directory.Exists(FilePath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath);

        foreach (var file in upload.File)
        {

            var filePath = Path.Combine(FilePath, file.FileName);

            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fs);
                continue;
            }
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

## CSHTML:

```
@model SvivaTeamVersion3.Models.ReportModel

<h4>Add Report</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="ProcessReport">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="category" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="category" class="form-control" />*@
                <select asp-for="category" name="Category" id="Category" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Road">Road problems</option>
                    <option value="Urban">Urban problems</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="category" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="title" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="title" class="form-control" />*@
                <select asp-for="title" id="Road_Problems1" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Accident">Accident</option>
                    <option value="Disturptive_object">Disturptive object</option>
                    <option value="Disturptive_parkings">Disturptive parking</option>
                    <option value="Defective_indication">Defective indication</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>

                <select asp-for="title" id="Urban_problems1" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Neigborhood_problen">Neigborhood problen</option>
                    <option value="Pollution">Pollution</option>
                    <option value="Animals">Animals</option>
                    <option value="Disturptive_object">Disturptive object</option>
                    <option value="Tag">Tag</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>

                <select asp-for="title" id="Other1" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="title" class="text-danger"></span>

                <style>
                    .form-group #Other1, #Urban_problems1 {
                        display: none;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="coordLat" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="lat" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="coordLong" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="long" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="remarks" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="remarks" class="form-control" id="remarks" style="height: 140px; width: 100%"/>*@
                <textarea asp-for="remarks" maxlength="250" id="remarks" class="form-control" cols="50" rows="10" style="height: 140px; width: 100%; resize:none;"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="remarks" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="statUrgence" class="control-label"></label>
                @*<input asp-for="statUrgence" class="form-control" />*@
                <select asp-for="statUrgence" name="statUrgence" id="statUrgence" class="form-control">
                    <option value="veryUrgent">Very Urgent</option>
                    <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
                    <option value="NotUrgent">Not Urgent</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="statUrgence" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            @*<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="File" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="File" class="" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
            <span asp-validation-for="File" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>*@

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" id="File_Upload" name="File" onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" multiple />
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn-default" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }

            <div class="form-group" id="display_image" style="display: none; overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px; width: auto;">
                <output id="result" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:400px; width:auto; "></output>
            </div>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ol.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/ol-ext.css">


            <script src="~/js/ol.js"></script>

            <script src="~/js/ol-ext.js"></script>

            @*<script src="~/js/elm-pep"></script>*@

            @*<script src="~/js/JavaScript.js"></script>*@

            <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px;">
                <div class="photon ol-search ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed">
                    <input type="search" class="search" placeholder="Search..."> @*autocomplete="off"*@
                    <input type="button" class="ol-revers" title="click on the map">
                    <ul class="autocomplete history">
                        <li data-search="0"> 398<i> 9350004 Jérusalem (Israël)</i></li>
                        <li class="copy"><a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="new">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="button-70" style="z-index:1;" id="location-button">
                @*<button id="location-button" title="Get your location"></button>*@
                @*<button asp-for="coordinates" class="button-70" id="location-button" role="button" title="Get your current location"> Get cuttent location</button>*@
                <input type="button" value=" Get current location" id="location-button" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" id="AddReportToDB" value="Add Report" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

            <script>
                var lat = 0;
                var long = 0;

                var layers = [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })];

                var map = new ol.Map({
                    target: 'map',
                    view: new ol.View({
                        zoom: 5,
                        center: [166326, 5992663]
                    }),
                    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: false, pinchRotate: false}),
                    layers: layers
                });

                var search = new ol.control.SearchPhoton({
                    lang: "fr",
                    reverse: true,
                    position: true
                });
                map.addControl(search);

                var markers;
                search.on('select', function (e) {

                    map.getView().animate({
                        center: e.coordinate,
                        zoom: Math.max(map.getView().getZoom(), 16)
                    });

                    loc(e.coordinate);

                });

                function loc(e) {
                    lat = e[0];
                    long = e[1];
                    updateValue(lat, long);
                    console.log(lat, long); //MARKED
                    if (markers) {
                        map.removeLayer(markers)
                    }

                    markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                        style: new ol.style.Style({
                            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                                anchor: [0.5, 1],
                                src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                            })
                        })
                    });

                    map.addLayer(markers);

                    var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e));
                    markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);
                }

                document.querySelector("#location-button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                            console.log(position["coords"]["latitude"], position["coords"]["longitude"]); //MARKED
                            if (markers) {
                                map.removeLayer(markers)
                            }

                            lat = position["coords"]["latitude"];
                            long = position["coords"]["longitude"];
                            markers = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                source: new ol.source.Vector(),
                                style: new ol.style.Style({
                                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                                        anchor: [0.5, 1],
                                        src: 'https://ucarecdn.com/4b516de9-d43d-4b75-9f0f-ab0916bd85eb/marker.png' // => https://app.uploadcare.com/projects/c05bbeb5e1a61e862903/files/7110cd57-b0ee-4833-bcd1-ff0343dd01cc/?limit=100&ordering=-datetime_uploaded
                                    })
                                })
                            });

                            map.addLayer(markers);

                            var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])));
                            markers.getSource().addFeature(marker);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
                    }
                });

                function updateValue(lat, long) {
                    document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
                    document.getElementById("long").value = long;
                }
            </script>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<style>
    .button-70 #location-button {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        transform: scale(2)
    }

    .button-70 {
        transform: scale(0.7);
        background-image: linear-gradient(#0dccea, #0d70ea);
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 0 5px 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
        font-size: .9em;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        touch-action: manipulation;
    }
</style>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Update, I think the <form asp-action="ProcessReport"> and the Html.BeginForm(...) just can't work together. I tried to move the Html.BeginForm(...) out of the form and it worked. The images were saved but the other data didn't. How do I combine those and/or make it work?

Comment: Hi @David, why not move your logic in `ProcessReport` action to the `Upload` action? And why not combine all the inputs/select to one form?